# Invalid character in name at (1) with fixed-form source

Tags: fortran, gfortran, fortran77

I am getting an eror "Invalid character in name at (1)" in my Fortran 77 program.  Why is this?

It is in my read statement

```
      100 READ(S,*,END=200) LINE
```

but I am not sure why

Code:

```
      PROGRAM Exercise
C
C PARAMETERS
C
      INTEGER UNUM
      PARAMETER (UNUM=15)
C
C LOCAL VARIABLES
C
      REAL LINES

C
C FUNCTION DECLARATIONS
C
      REAL NUMLIN
C
C COMMON VARIABLES
C

C
C DATA STATEMENTS
C


C MAIN PROGRAM MODULE
C

      OPEN(UNIT=UNUM, FILE = 'line.txt', STATUS='OLD')
      LINES=NUNMLIN(UNUM)

C
C Rewinding to the top of the file because the pointer is at the end
C of the file
C

      REWIND(UNUM)
      CLOSE(UNUM)

      CALL PROCES(UNUM,LINES)

      STOP
      END PROGRAM

CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC
C SUBROUTINE PROCES
C
C dynamically allocates space
C

      SUBROUTINE PROCES(U,L)

CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC
C FUNCTIONS
C
C NUMLIN -  counts the number of lines, uses the fact that the file
C is already open and passes this information to the next subroutine
C
      REAL FUNCTION NUMLIN(S)
      REAL NUMLIN
      REAL S

      CHARACTER*256 LINE
      100 READ(S,*,END=200) LINE
      NUMLIN=NUMLIN+1
      GOTO 100
      200 CONTINUE

      RETURN
      END
```

Error:

```
NumberCountingExercise.for:90.7:

      100 READ(S,*,END=200) LINE                                        
       1
Error: Invalid character in name at (1)
NumberCountingExercise.for:93.7:

      200 CONTINUE                                                      
       1
Error: Invalid character in name at (1)
NumberCountingExercise.for:85.27:
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In fixed source form, a statement label should appear in columns 1 to 5.

`100` and `200` are (starting in column 7) in the statement field and are taken as being part of entities' names.  A name must begin with a letter.

Comment: So would I just backspace them? I am confused-- they are at the beginning of the line

Comment: For the first, you want `READ` to start no earlier than column 7, and the `100` to be wholly within columns 1 to 5.  Something like `100   READ...`.  In your code example the `1` is aligned with `C` in the line above (which can be correct only if that is column 1 or 6).